# How to replace PVC Valve

Tags: plumbing, pool

Pictured is a broken valve on a pipe that is part of a pool heating system.  The pipe sends water to a solar heater on the roof.  We bought the house its in its current state but I assume the handle was broken off and the valve seems to be stuck closed.  Being totally new to this I'm wondering:

1. Is there anyway to fix this without replacing the valve?
2. What kind of valve do I replace this with? A combined ball and check valve?
3. Does replacing it means cutting out the broken valve?
   [image]

Comment: In the meantime, a Cresent™ type, smooth-jawed adjustable wrench looks like it would operate the valve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those look like compression fittings.   You should be able to unscrew them:  Make note of which way the compression rings (O-rings) are seated (if there are any).

You should be able to buy a replacement.  Here's a similar one:

[image]

Comment: "unions" not compression rings. but otherwise yes.

Comment: Are "unions" what they call the rings that get slightly squished between the two pieces to get a water tight seal?

Comment: "O rings" are the seal, union is the system of the loose ring that screws onto the fixed bibb clamping the flange and the bibb together.